# Does [a/the] binary search algorithm imply

Tags: articles

I'm curious about what article should I use. I want to ask the following question:

> Does **[a/the]** binary search algorithm imply distinct keys?

On the one hand, binary search algorithm is one of many searching algorithms. On the other hand, I'm not talking about a search algorithm in general but I'm talking about the specific one.

Comment: Apparently, there's such a thing as a [***Noisy binary search***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which I imagine would be relevant if you were trying to perform a binary search on a table potentially containing duplicate keys. Btw - I think most people would use ***unique keys*** rather than ***distinct keys*** in your context. To clarify that you're talking about a *specific* algorithm, I suggest you ask *Does **this** algorithm [have such-and-such an attribute?]*

Comment: (Note that ***the*** could be contextually inferred to refer to the specific algorithm being discussed, but ***a*** would imply ***any and all binary search algorithms*** - to which per my preceding comment, the answer would obviously be ***No, not necessarily***.)